# How can I return string instead of bool in lambda?

Tags: c++

> How can I return string "x is less than y" or  "x is greater than y" instead of bool values in this case ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    auto compare = [](int x, int y) { return  x < y; };
    cout << ((n == m) ? "the same" : to_string(compare(n, m)));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `std::cout << std::boolalpha;` (which is a sticky flag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto compare = [](int x, int y) {
  return x < y ? "x is less than y" : "x is greater than y";
};
```

Comment: string or const char* :-)

Comment: The OP didn't specify what kind of string she/he wants, `std::string` or char array. I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: `compare(0,0)` --> "x is greater than y"

Comment: I have one question, why I have to surround by brackets all expression `cout << ((n == m) ? "the same" : compare(n, m));` ? When I write `cout << (n == m) ? "the same" : compare(n, m);` it produces wrong results.

Comment: @T-kin-ter [Operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). It is parsed as  `(cout << (n == m)) ? "the same" : compare(n, m);`.